# Android Espresso - Testing on different Activities

Tags: android, integration-testing, android-espresso, gmsplacepicker

I'm writing tests for my Android App with the Espresso framework. This seems to work fine so far. Problem is that I sometimes have to change the Activity.

In this specific case clicking a button opens the Google PlacePicker for selecting a certain position. But meanwhile this Activity is shown, Espresso is waiting for the next step. So instead of interacting in this Activity it stalls until I manually close the Place Picker (or the timeout is reached).

So it looks like this:

```
onView(withId(R.id.origin)).perform(click()); // opens PlacePicker    
onView(...)  // is only executed the moment I manually close the PlacePicker
```

So is there an option to tell Espresso that the Activity has changed in order to select a place and return to my activity? I can't do any interaction in the PlacePicker, no view element can be found from the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espresso works with only one activity. It is designed to test activities.

You can simulate PlacePicker call by manually calling your `onActivityResult` with some fake (manually created) Intent.

So call

```
onActivityResult(PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST, RESULT_OK, intent)
```

instead of

```
onView(withId(R.id.origin)).perform(click()); // opens PlacePicker
```

Comment: It is very flexible, just play with it some time. Here is a good quick review of some unordinary features - https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/lists/index.html